# Use another action in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, controller, action

I have a edit cart form and I would like to call another action (with a button_to or link_to) before the submit button (which calls "update"). Is it posible in RoR ? Thank you in advance !

Comment: Please adding your code next time :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes, rails can do. Try:

```
<%= link_to "Update", update_carts_path(@path.id) %>
```

for example, but. If this **update** was update when you are editing that chart. That `submit button` had already taking handle on it. Submit on rails can assumed to be smart button action that will automatically change depend on your action, `post` for `create` and `put` for `update`

FYI, You can check your list of path with `rake routes` on terminal.

Sorry for mess description, kind of newbie.

Comment: In fact, when you insert a link_to (or button_to) within a form, whatever the action required in this link, it will always be the submit action which will be called instead of the action required in your link. But I found a solution using <f.submit "Your text", :name => "your params"> which enables to insert multiple actions into one controller (depending on the params["your params"]).

Comment: Oh yes, I'm sorry forgot about that, Yes that right, and then just calling it from controller with `if params[:name]`. Next time please insert your code so your question will be clear enough to helped. Thanks